# How can I store letter frequency in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm wanting to have an array length 26 (for each character of the alphabet). And when a phrase is written in the command line argument, the frequency of each letter is stored in that array.

What is my best way of doing this?

Comment: You should describe what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

By assuming that there are only lower case ASCII characters ....

```
int hits = new int[26];
String s =... ;

 for(char c: s.toCharArray())
    hits[c- 'a'] ++;
```

This is of course not the best way of doing, but can be a good starting point.

Comment: Yep.  But you could just store any ASCII character in a 256 array and then just index it directly.